# Hover Box Color and Image Opacity

Tags: html, css

I have an image and text below it wrapped in one "a" tag. Hovering over the white box with text in it turns the box grey. Hovering over the image and it has an opacity effect.

How can I make the box turn grey and the image opacity happen at the same time when hovered over. At the moment these happen seperately. This is not a huge problem but it'd look better if they happened together.

Here's a screenshot - https://imgsafe.org/image/ef3964b27c

This is my HTML;

```html
<div class="w3-third w3-container w3-margin-bottom">
  <a href="#" style="display:block">
    <img src="Images/MCR.png" style="width:100%" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    <div class="w3-container w3-white">
      <p><b>PSB2 and COM4</b></p>
      <p><b>&nbsp;</b></p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: add css code also

Answer (score 1):

Since your snippet is different from the image you provided, I created a simple snippet that changes the opacity of the image and changes the border color *(if that is what you mean by box)* to gray

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
.wrapper:hover {
  border: 3px solid gray;
}
.wrapper:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

now try this one with edited code

```css
.w3-white {
  margin-top: -20px;
  width: 40%;
}

.w3-container:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.w3-container:hover .w3-white {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-third w3-container w3-margin-bottom">
  <a href="#" style="display:block"><img src="http://webneel.com/daily/sites/default/files/images/daily/09-2013/1-diwali-greetings.preview.jpg" style="width:40%" class="w3-hover-opacity">
    <div class="w3-container w3-white">
      <p><b>PSB2 and COM4</b></p>
      <p><b>&nbsp;</b></p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You seemed to disregarded the "box turn grey" part

Comment: which box color explain more

Comment: You better ask OP, not me

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to get the image to go opacity and the white box with the text in underneath to turn grey at the same time. Ignore the green box around it...that's the page colour background. At the moment the image goes opacity if you hover over that, but the box stays white unless you hover over it...I want both to do their thing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
.w3-third {
    border: 5px solid lightgreen;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.w3-third:hover .w3-white {
    background-color: gray;
}

.w3-third:hover img {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-third w3-container w3-margin-bottom">
    <a href="#" style="display:block"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEnn9dYYZlciBKfaHCw17-dUgRPX3nq5_6-kV1ua-LIsId5g43uA">
    <div class="w3-container w3-white">
        <p><b>PSB2 and COM4</b></p>
        <p><b>&nbsp;</b></p>
    </div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put you image and text into a single container and add simple transition. check below snippet.

```css
.img-container {
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.img-container p {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin:0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.img-container img{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.img-container:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.img-container:hover p {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" />
    <p>Some text</p>
  </a>
</div>
```